# Standard Publisher Actions not Appearing

Tags: salesforce1-app, publisher, global-actions, custom-actions

I added a set of standard publisher actions (e.g. thanks, poll, file etc.) to some of the standard objects (e.g. accounts, contacts).
Looking at the available publisher actions in SF1 via Chrome, iPhone and iPad and cant see these standard functions appear despite being defined in the page-layout.

Secondly, in many cases Chrome simply fails to show the publisher plus sign whereas iPhone/iPad do - anyone know how to workaround that?

Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this is that Chatter Feed Tracking isn't enabled on the standard objects you're looking at in S1. Prior to Summer '14, actions only appeared on the object detail page when Chatter Feed Tracking was enabled for the object.

As of Summer '14, actions appear on the object regardless of whether Chatter Feed Tracking is enabled for that object, but if it isn't enabled, then you won't see the standard Chatter actions, only Create a Record, Log a Call, Update a Record or Custom action types.